# Angular .reset() gives error on test env but is working perfectly on dev

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, primeng

I'm using angular 14, I have a form that is filters for a table. when I try to reset a form it is working on my machine but it gives an error when it is ran on test environment.

here is an error message:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '_pendingValue' of object '[object Object]'
    at FormControl._applyFormState (main.ec267cc59c801252.js:123875:39)
    at FormControl.reset (main.ec267cc59c801252.js:123797:10)
    at main.ec267cc59c801252.js:122817:15
    at main.ec267cc59c801252.js:122864:18
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at FormGroup._forEachChild (main.ec267cc59c801252.js:122859:32)
    at FormGroup.reset (main.ec267cc59c801252.js:122816:10)
    at AmlNewGenCasesComponent.initFilterForm (807.bc72eefe3ce58b53.js:601:40)
    at AmlNewGenCasesComponent.onFilterClear (807.bc72eefe3ce58b53.js:722:18)
    at AmlNewGenCasesComponent_ng_template_79_Template_p_button_click_2_listener (template.html:103:38)
```

and here is the method responsible for it:

```
onFilterClear() {
    if (FormsHelper.isAnyFieldPopulated(this.newGenCasesFilterForm)) {
      this.newGenCasesFilterForm.reset();
      this.initFilterForm();
      this.store.dispatch(getNewGen({gridFilter: this.newGenCasesFilter}));
    } else {
      this.messageService.add({severity: 'info', summary: 'ფილტრი', detail: 'ფილტრი ცარიელია'})
    }
  }
```

I tried replacing `this.newGenCasesFilterForm.reset();` this with `this.newGenCasesFilterForm.resetForm();` but it errors out saying `TS2339: Property 'resetForm' does not exist on type 'FormGroup '.`

Comment: issue still not solved, only thing I did was to remove ngrx from this approach and use good old services.